# fixture 'loop' not found

Tags: python, pytest, sanic

I run the following test in Sanic using PyTest, but I am getting

fixture 'loop' not found

error, I followed the tutorial in the [link](https://sanic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sanic/testing.html) where in make app returns Sanic app.

```
import pytest
import json

from main import make_app

@pytest.yield_fixture
def app():
    app = make_app()
    yield app

@pytest.fixture
def test_cli(loop, app, test_client):
    return loop.run_until_complete(test_client(app))



async def test_fixture_test_client_post(test_cli):

    data = {
    "urls" : [

                "https://images.pexels.com/photos/789380/pexels-photo-789380.jpeg",
                "https://images.pexels.com/photos/280204/pexels-photo-280204.jpeg"
        ]
    }
    response = await test_cli.post('/v1/images/upload',data=json.dumps(data))

    assert response.status == 200
```

Comment: What does `pytest -v --collect-only | grep plugins` return?

Comment: nothing is returned

Comment: Then you need to `pip install pytest-sanic`. The `sanic` package doesn't include the plugin for `pytest`, it is in a separate package.

Comment: I already did that

Comment: I reinstalled and it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled pytest-sanic, and reinstalled and it worked.

as @hoefling mentioned in the comments,

running this command `pytest -v --collect-only | grep plugins`
showed that the plugin wasn't installed properly